# exported app (android) doesnt have the whole functions

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, export, apk

When I install the app directly from android studio onto my phone per usb everything works well. I am working with push notifications that work with this method. But when I export my app in android studio and get the apk file and then install it per this apk file onto my phone  everything works but not the notification??

Do you understand what I mean?
I can play my app per android studio directly onto my phone and it works 100% well ( I also get the expected push notifications).

After the export I get an apk file. I install this apk file manually and I get my app which looks great at first, only the notifications dont come although they come when I install it per android studio directly.

What am I doing wrong? Isnt the apk file the right file? Maybe I need another file? The code must be good because everything is fine when pushing play in android studio.

EDIT: Here is my code for the notifications:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import java.util.Random;

public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationHelper";

    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannels();
        }
    }

    private String CHANNEL_NAME = "High priority channel";
    private String CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.notifications" + CHANNEL_NAME;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannels() {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("this is the description of the channel.");
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    public void sendHighPriorityNotification(String title, String body, Class activityName) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityName);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 267, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
//                .setContentTitle(title)
//                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText("summary").setBigContentTitle(title).bigText(body))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);


    }

}
```

And here is my code where I call the notification:

```
package com.example.geofencing1;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.List;

public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceBroadcastReceiv";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        // Toast.makeText(context, "Geofence triggered...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()){
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Error receiving geofence event...");
            return;
        }


        List<Geofence> geofenceList = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        for (Geofence geofence: geofenceList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + geofence.getRequestId());
        }
//        Location location = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
        int transitionType = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER", "", MapsActivity.class);
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL", "", MapsActivity.class);
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT", "", MapsActivity.class);
                break;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: how does you indicate notification showing? "manually" by own code or basing on some 3rd party software/service (e.g. Firebase)?

Comment: I used a class "NotificationHelper" that I found in the internet. It seems to be only code and not based on a 3rd party software

Comment: I cant send code here because too long but maybe it helps you: the class extends ContextWrapper